# How to add a subdomain in cloudflare for my azure container which requires a port number to access it

Tags: azure, dns, containers, cloudflare

I have a metabase docker image running on my Azure container. It can be accessed through azure's fqdn:port_number (port is 3000) or ip:port_number. I want to give a nice domain name for this application through cloudflare(. How can I do this?
Thanks in Advance!

PS: There were some topics on this in cloudflare community but I couldn't fine any answer relevant for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `CNAME` record to point subdomain such as `www.example.com` to the FQDN value of your Azure container like `containerdns.westus.azurecontainer.io`.

Example of a CNAME record:

```
name: www    
record type: CNAME    
value:  FQDN value of your Azure container
TTL: 32600
```

[image]
ref: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-cname-record/
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019093151-

### Update

From your comment, you want to access `myapp.com` which actually points to `fqdn:port`. In this case, you could create and configure an application gateway to host web sites with custom ports using the Azure portal. If you have multiple sites, you could follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-multiple-sites-portal) tutorial.

You could follow the steps below:

1. Create a public-facing application gateway with a public IP address in the same region as your container instance.
2. Create a backend pool with target hostname of your container FQDN like `containerdns.westus.azurecontainer.io`
3. Create a basic listener and provide name, frontend port **80** and protocol HTTP.
4. Create a health probe, provide protocol HTTP, check the box `Pick host name from backend http settings` and the remaining setting is the default.
5. Add an HTTP-settings with custom port **3000** as your desired and check the box `Pick host name from backend address` and use custom probe and select custom probe.
6. Create a basic rule with the backend pool and HTTP setting.
7. In the end, you could create a `CNAME` record mapping the subdomain `www.myapp.com` to the FQDN of your application gateway.

I validate this on my website on Azure VM, hope this could help you.

Comment: But I'm unable to add port number in CNAME record. I need to have that portnumber to access my application. So I'm looking for a way in which I can access my application directly at say example myapp.com which actually points to fqdn:port